# Create Azure SQL Server VM including backup

Tags: azure, azure-sql-server, azure-backup-vault

I'm trying to deploy a SQL Server VM via ARM template and set backup in the same template.
I've managed to set up the VM and added the VM to backup but not the databases.

I've tried to use some of the quickstart templates on Github, but I don't find any that ascociate the SQL with a backup policy.
I want to enable auto backup on all databases and ascociate a backup policy.

Anyone have any example template?

Answer (score 0):

[Auto backup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-automated-backups?tabs=single-database) is one of the features of Azure SQL, you don't need to do set it manually, it's automatically.

Configure your backup policy by [Change Backup Retention Period](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-automated-backups?tabs=single-database#how-to-change-the-pitr-backup-retention-period) between 7 to 35 days.

For **Azure SQL Managed instance**:

Powershell command:

```
Set-AzSqlDatabaseBackupShortTermRetentionPolicy -ResourceGroupName resourceGroup -ServerName testserver -DatabaseName testDatabase -RetentionDays 28
```

REST API:

Sample Request

```
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/00000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444/resourceGroups/resourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/testserver/databases/testDatabase/backupShortTermRetentionPolicies/default?api-version=2017-10-01-preview
```

Request Body

```
{
  "properties":{
    "retentionDays":28
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
But I guess your answer is only valid for Azure SQL Server and not Azure SQL Virtual Machine? Or have I misunderstood something perhaps?

What I want to do is what is described in this article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-sql-server-database-azure-vms

But I want to do it in an ARM template.